# Laravel Eloquent - Unable to get relations to work when setting database dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I can think of a couple sloppy workarounds for this issue, but I am curious if there is an Eloquent-sanctioned way to do this.

I have a model for which the database is set dynamically:

Let's say I have a model called Tree.

```
$tree = new Tree();
$myTree = $tree->setConnection($connection)->find(1);
```

The tree model has a hasMany() relation with the Branch model, so to get all of this tree's branches I use the standard Eloquent method:

```
$myBranches = $myTree->branch()->get();
```

This throws an error because the SQL query reverts to the default db connection (where these tables do not exist), not the dynamically selected connection which I just set for the Tree model.

Is there an eloquenty way to get the Branch model to use the same database as its parent?

Comment: Can you have your relationship `return $this->connection('foobar')->hasMany(...);`?

Comment: unfortunately, that does not work.

Comment: You might want to mention which version of Laravel/Eloquent you are using.  This looks like 4.x, but would be good to know for sure.

Comment: Laravel 5.2. BTW I gave up on an Eloquent way to do this and decided to just do a workaround.